# Hazelcast Mapstore: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket

Tags: oracle, hazelcast

I use Hazelcast and use MapStore to load and store data in Oracle database. It works fine most of the time. But after idling the Hazelcast for a period of time, I encountered "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket".

After I restart the Hazelcast instance, it works normally.

Would anyone advise what I could do to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a stracktrace of the exception? I reckon it's an issue in your MapLoader implementation. I reckon an idle connection is closed either by your DB or a firewall sitting in between Hazelcast and the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked the stacktrace of the exception, and the error indeed happens at the MapStore load() function. I will check the database connection to keep the connection alive. 

By the way, as MapStore will write data to DB every 1 minute, should I keep DB connection always connecting to DB, or should only connect to DB when MapStore store() function is called? Will the latter approach prevent the idle DB connection timeout issue?

Comment: I found several log from Hazelcast HealthMonitor, and it shows decrease of free memory.

"Apr 29, 2016 3:43:38 AM com.hazelcast.internal.monitors.HealthMonitor
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.5.4] processors=1, physical.memory.total=1.8G, physical.memory.free=335.8M, 
swap.space.total=9.8G............"

What does it mean? Is there any problem, eg. memory leak? If so, how should I fix the problem?